# Single Phase Sine Inverter

Tags: inverter

[image: hbridge mosfet]

Can somebody tell my why that gain and integrator (and negative feedback gain) circuit is used to measure the current?

This is the basic H bridge circuit, mosfet is used as switch here, and gate signal is provided. DC voltage source is 100V.

I just want to know why that gain and integrator blocks are used to get the output current.

Comment: Ugh. That annoying blue background with white components creates so much contrast that it's hard to see the circuit.  There are conventions for drawing schematics.  Ignoring them is thumbing your nose at those you seek help from.  No thanks.

Comment: This isn't a circuit diagram per-say. This is a Matlab:Simulink model

Answer (score 1):

For starters that is a poorly layed out simulink model (no offence if it is yours).
Secondly, that integrator, error block and gain block are there to simulate an inductive-Resistive load

Gain1 is the resistance component (12R)
Gain7 is the inductive component.

Simpowersystems comes with inductors so what is done here isn't needed.
HOWEVER this is done if you need todo some sort of varying inductance (eg motor stator)

Matlab:simulink is an integrator engine so if you can realise an equation in terms of int(x,t) it is very effient and continuous can be used

Comment: Thanks Naib, can you explain in detail how that gain 7 is used as a inductor, is it like Xl = sL or some other concept

Comment: Gain1 = Inductive component, Gain7 = Resistive component. Its implementing the R + L load & in the continuous time domain: V = Ri + Ldi/dt. By re-arranging that equation to better suit the integrator engine of Simulink (you REALLY do not want d/dt elements....) you end up with: V - Ri = L di/dt.   So gain7 == R (in Ohms) and Gain1 == 1/L (in Henries)

Comment: If you look into the circuit model, MOSFET used is N-channel mosfet but instead of connecting the positive terminal of DC source to DRAIN it is connected to SOURCE terminal, so interchanging that would affect the inverter configuration or not ??

and the load which is suppose to be connected in the middle of H-bridge is connected with the voltage measurement, my question is how current is flowing through the load parameter, its too confusing

Comment: that is true, the FET's need to be connected up correctly. As it stands the intrinsic diode model will "short circuit" the supply and it will not function. Flipping all the FET's the correct way round should allow a reasonable current to flow in the pseudo-load for a given pwm pattern